# How do I make one of two inline buttons fill the remaining available space?

Tags: html, css

I have two inline buttons, the left button has 20px padding, the other needs to have 20px of padding but also needs to take up the remaining space. Both have margin of 10px between them.

I've tried floating and table-cell but can't achieve my desired result. Browser support isn't and issue. I'd like to avoid using JS if possible please.

Please see the image below for a visual explanation.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Add your `HTML` markup and css, then only can anyone understand question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.btnset {
  display: flex; // added
}
.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
.btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 10px; // added space between the two buttons
}
.btn2 {
  width: 100%; // so that the div takes available width
}
```

```html
<div class="btnset">
  <button class="btn btn1">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn2">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The magic of **flex boxes**, so let's try this snippet:

```css
.wrapper-btns {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-btns .btn-back, .wrapper-btns .btn-next {
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper-btns .btn-back {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.wrapper-btns .btn-next {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-btns">
  <button class="btn-back">Back</button>
  <button class="btn-next">Next</button>
</div>
```

> Flex boxes give you the control you have wished css had for so many years.
>   [More info..](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all use box-sizing: border-box. It will count its padding as its total width. And another advice more related to question is to use min-width property on the button that you want to fill remaining size.